# How to control the position of columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, variables, position, multiple-columns

I have this dataframe

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:5,
                y = 6:10,
                z = 11:15,
                o = 16:20,
                m = 21:25)
```

And I want to change the position of columns in a simple way as follows :

1st column : m

2st column : z

3st column : o

4st column : x

5st column : y

How can we do that with a simple function ? Thanks.

Comment: You can do either `df[c(5, 3, 4, 1, 2)]` or `df[c('m', 'z', 'o', 'x', 'y')]` or if you are using dplyr `df %>% select(m, z, o, x, y)`

Comment: Thanks. You can add it to the answer section if you want to make the answer accesible for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```r
df[c(5, 3, 4, 1, 2)]
```

or

```
df[c('m', 'z', 'o', 'x', 'y')]
```

or

```r
df |> with(data.frame(m, z, o, x, y))
```

or if you are using dplyr

```r
df %>% select(m, z, o, x, y)
```

All of which result in

```r
   m  z  o x  y
1 21 11 16 1  6
2 22 12 17 2  7
3 23 13 18 3  8
4 24 14 19 4  9
5 25 15 20 5 10
```